# Composition not importing in Node files: Remotion

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am getting this error:
./node_modules/@remotion/player/dist/esm/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Composition' from non ECMAScript module (only default export is available)

All packages are installed, I am using TS.

I added the type: module to to package.json but the code is crashing. The React Scripts version is 4.0.1. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.